# Does a "scholastic record" include research papers, or only reflect how well the student did in classes (~GPA)?

Tags: word-meaning

I am being asked to judge a master's student for some research program (Ph.D.). Amongst other questions, I am being asked this question:

> Do you have any reason to believe that the applicant's scholastic record, as you know it, is not an accurate index of his or her scholastic ability? If so, please explain.

Does a "scholastic record" include research papers the student may have published? Or does a "scholastic record" only reflect how well the student did in classes (~GPA)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a student who has completed or nearly completed a master's degree, and is being considered for s Ph.D. program, I would expect that any papers the student has written, particularly if they were written about work done as part of the master's, would be considered part of the  "scholastic record". But there is no one set definition on what is considered part of the  "scholastic record", the only way to be sure what the Ph.D. admissions people want is to ask them.